# How to track what removed a module?

Tags: ruby

I have an issue that `HTTP::auth` is available under normal circumstances but not defined under a project with lots of dependencies.

I have the gem in `Gemfile.lock`, I have the necessary `require 'http'` statement. Issue is that already `httpclient` and `http-cookie` gems also modify same `HTTP` module.

The thing is that inside the project I only see what was defined by the `http-cookie` jar. But `http` is already required.

```
[3] pry(#<ReportPortal::HttpClient>)> ls HTTP
constants: Accept  Cookie  CookieJar
[4] pry(#<ReportPortal::HttpClient>)> require 'http'
=> false
```

My conclusion is that something uses `remove_const` to remove the `HTTP` module in the middle for whatever reason. And I want to find and violently destroy it.

Please give me ideas how to track this down.

Comment: Try `::HTTP::auth`

Comment: Can't reproduce with these 3 gems. What I'd do next is get the source code of the possible offenders and scan it for suspicious code (`remove_const` and the like). If no results, bundle/vendor all the gems into a folder and scan all of them.

Comment: Would be so much easier if every gem would stay in its own namespace

Comment: Another way to go about this is to clone the project and start removing dependencies one by one until that name is available again. Then you'd know who's at fault.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, `::` exactly same result. And no help with grep. But now I inserted `require 'pry' ; binding.pry` inside `http.rb`. It is never called even though `require 'http'` returns false inside another pry breakpoint. Do you have any idea what could confuse ruby to think file was loaded while it never was?

Comment: is it a file or `gem "http"`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that was the right question. It turned out there is a `http.rb` in load path. Although it touches another namespace only, it confuses ruby `require`. Thanks a lot! If you write an answer, I'll accept although the way question is phrased makes little sense.